# Where do I find `PayPalAPI.PayPalAPIInitialize()`

Tags: c#, api, paypal

I am performing a Paypal `DoCapture` from C# .Net. I have downloaded the Paypal ASP.Net NVP SDK from the website and and am currently looking at the sample code for the `DoCapture` I wish to perform.

At the top of the class, the following references are added, so I have been sure to add these to my own class (and yes I have added the appropriate `*.dll` file to my project):

```
using com.paypal.sdk.core;
using com.paypal.sdk.services;
using com.paypal.sdk.util;
```

The next line is below, it basically runs a method called `PayPalAPIInitialize` which is part of the PayPalAPI class and returns an `NVPCallerServices` object.

```
NVPCallerServices caller = PayPalAPI.PayPalAPIInitialize();
```

This just isn't working for me. I am using the same `*.dll` the sample code is. I have also added every possible Paypal reference to my code as shown below:

```
using com.paypal;
using com.paypal.sdk;
using com.paypal.sdk.core;
using com.paypal.sdk.core.nvp;
using com.paypal.sdk.exceptions;
using com.paypal.sdk.logging;
using com.paypal.sdk.profiles;
using com.paypal.sdk.resources;
using com.paypal.sdk.rules;
using com.paypal.sdk.services;
using com.paypal.sdk.util;
```

Am I doing something stupid here or have Paypal messed up (I'm assuming it is the former, but I can't figure out what!)?

Thanks

Comment: What error do you get? Can it not find the type or function? Does [this](http://paypaldev.org/yaf_postst18050_Error-invoking-PayPalAPIPayPalAPIInitialize.aspx) help any?